# System.Net.Http reference properties path not showing NuGet packages path

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, nuget, project-reference

I have a solution with a number of projects.

I have changed system.Net.http to use the NuGet version, and most projects, when i select the "System.Net.Http" reference in the references node of solution explorer, it shows the path as "X:\myPath\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib etc..."

[image: Correct Reference Path]

However, i have a couple of projects when removing reference to System.Net.Http then going to NuGet Package Manager and installing it, when you click reference in the reference node, the path shows as "C:\Program Files etc.... Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\"

[image: Incorrect Reference Path]

I have opened the project file, and the "HintPath" is correct, however the path that shows in the reference Properties is incorrect.

[image: Project File HintPath]

When i look at Object Browser, it confirms this project is actually calling the framework version of System.Http.Net (so, even though i have installed NuGet version, and the HintPath is pointing to our packages folder, its still referencing the framework version)

Does anyone know why the path isnt matching and how I can fix this (so my project is using NuGet version instead of framework version to match the other projects in my solution?

Just incase it helps, here are all the references in the problem project:
[image: Problem project references]

Comment: Hi treendy, it seems you do the same steps on different projects and the results are different, right? Please right click the reference 'System.Net.Http' and Remove, then use the Manage Nuget Packages to install it again.

Comment: Thanks @SaraLiu-MSFT, I have tried that a few times, and still has the same outcome : (

Comment: Without giving us a sample to download and test on our own machines, it's very hard to guess what's going on/help you with this. You could try running "msbuild -pp" or "msbuild -bl" or "msbuild -v:diag" and search the results. It's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory: it's a hack implemented in Visual Studio in order to workaround an issue with the package `System.Net.Http`.

There are issues with this package and it seems we should not use it anymore. The version of the `System.Net.Http` library included in the .NET Framework is better starting from 4.7.2 if I understand correctly.

See:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17522#issuecomment-338418610
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29622

I'm currently moving projects to .NET Framework 4.8 and I'm removing all `System.Net.Http` packages.